# Jdk1.8.0 happen unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

I can run the program under teminal. But when I use the idea to run it, which happens :happen unsupported major.minor version 52.0

**java version**

```
yjb@user:~/IdeaProjects/First$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)
```

**IDEA library:**

[image: IDEA libraries]

**exception in idea:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: tmVarlib/tmVar : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
null at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
null at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
null at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
null at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
null at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
null at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
null at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
null at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
null at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
null at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
null at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
null at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
null at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
end error!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Answer (score 2):

Class version 52 ist Java 8; your module SDK definition is alright, but make sure that in the run configuration (Run/Edit configurations...) for your application the correct JRE is selected (normally that should be set to use the module's sdk).

Comment: After a day of pain this is the only solution that worked